# AppleScript lists and the whose clause

Tags: applescript

AppleScript beginner here, and still struggling with basic syntax.

This works:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set flagged to messages of inbox whose flagged status is true
    log count of flagged
end tell
```

this does not work:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set msgs to messages of inbox
    set flagged to msgs whose flagged status is true
    log count of flagged
end tell
```

Why? (I suspect it's a simple syntactic rule that is escaping me)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `set msgs to messages of inbox`, what you're really saying is `set msgs to GET messages of inbox` as AppleScript performs a `get` command automatically if you don't tell it otherwise, the result of which is an AppleScript list (of message references), e.g.:

```
{message id 123 of mailbox "Inbox" ..., message 124 of mailbox "Inbox" ...}
```

However, `whose` queries (references) only work on application objects, not on AppleScript lists, e.g.:

```
every item of {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} where it > 3
-- error "Can’t get {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} whose it > 3." number -1728
```

Try the following instead:

```
tell application "Mail"
    set msgs to a reference to messages of inbox
    set flagged to msgs whose flagged status is true
    log count of flagged
end tell
```